# How to use auto increment for primary key id in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to dynamodb. I want to auto increment id value when I use `putitem` with dynamodb.

Is possible to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UUID in DynamoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721308/how-to-make-a-uuid-in-dynamodb)

Comment: or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264236/dynamodb-auto-incremented-id-server-time-ios-sdk

Answer (score 112):

This is anti-pattern in DynamoDB which is build to scale across many partitions/shards/servers. DynamoDB does not support auto-increment primary keys due to scaling limitations and cannot be guaranteed across multiple servers.

Better option is to assemble primary key from multiple indices. Primary key can be up to 2048 bytes. There are few options:

1. Use **UUID** as your key - possibly time based UUID which makes it unique, evenly distributed and carries time value
2. Use randomly generated number or timestamp + random (possibly bit-shifting) like: ts << 12 + random_number
3. Use another service or DynamoDB itself to generate incremental unique id (requires extra call)

Following code will auto-increment counter in DynamoDB and then you can use it as primary key.

```js
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
  TableName: 'sampletable',
  Key: { HashKey : 'counters' },
  UpdateExpression: 'ADD #a :x',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#a' : "counter_field"},
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {':x' : 1},
  ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW" // ensures you get value back
};
documentClient.update(params, function(err, data) {});
// once you get new value, use it as your primary key
```

My personal favorite is using timestamp + random inspired by Instagram's Sharding ID generation at http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

Following function will generate id for a specific shard (provided as parameter). This way you can have unique key, which is assembled from  timestamp, shard no. and some randomness (0-512).

```js
var CUSTOMEPOCH = 1300000000000; // artificial epoch
function generateRowId(shardId /* range 0-64 for shard/slot */) {
  var ts = new Date().getTime() - CUSTOMEPOCH; // limit to recent
  var randid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 512);
  ts = (ts * 64);   // bit-shift << 6
  ts = ts + shardId;
  return (ts * 512) + randid;
}
var newPrimaryHashKey = "obj_name:" + generateRowId(4);
// output is: "obj_name:8055517407349240"
```

Comment: Can you add more details about your 2nd point and the code at the end? Is `subId` supposed to be a shard ID or something?

Comment: @andrhamm It certainly looks like the shard id though 4? The ref article uses the formula userId % shardTotal (13 bits).

Comment: Please could explain the use of bit-shifting?

Comment: @vladaman
what is the point of using 

`var randid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 512);
...
randid % 512`


it should provide a number between 0 to 511 on the first line. Using modulo 512 for such a number does not change the number.

Comment: Have in mind that with this approach you cannot retrieve the timestamp from the id (like the instagram's example), since you don't know the random part.

Comment: i know i'm a little late to this, but could someone explain to me why an incremented partition key results in non-uniform distribution (or) bad sharding. From my point of view, it's just a number, unique to the given table due to the sole reason that it's (+1) to any existing id. It shouldn't matter to how it's partitioned right ?

Comment: How can I limit this with n digits? for example i want to create id of 9 digits only.

Comment: @TheAnimatrix the partition key should be used to logically group together data that would be commonly accessed together. Data with the same partition key will typically be stored physically close to other to optimize data retrieval. This is why dynamo supports a partition key and a sort key. The partition key is the same, the sort key increments, together they are unique.
I think this answer is misleading since in the linked article, IG are doing their own sharding and not using dynamo. I don't think you'd want to create a key like this using dynamo.

Answer (score 80):

DynamoDB doesn't provide this out of the box.  You can generate something in your application such as UUIDs that "should" be unique enough for most systems.

I noticed you were using Node.js (I removed your tag).  Here is a library that provides UUID functionality: [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid)

Example from README

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var uuid1 = uuid.v1();
var uuid2 = uuid.v1({node:[0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab]});
var uuid3 = uuid.v1({node:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
var uuid4 = uuid.v4();
var uuid5 = uuid.v4();
```

Comment: FWIW I use this approach (UUID as the hash key) with Dynamo and it has worked great.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct answer. It's also worth noting why: you want a uniform distribution of keys, and auto-incrementing would lead to a non-uniform distribution. See this article for more information: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=312527 and the AWS docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html

Comment: Use uuid as node-uuid is deprecated now.

Comment: Use KSUID (K-Sortable Globally Unique IDs) instead of UUID in the "sort key". In contrast to UUID, KSUID is sortable. Please refer to: https://github.com/segmentio/ksuid

Answer (score 4):

You probably can use [AtomicCounters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).

> With AtomicCounters, you can use the UpdateItem operation to implement
>   an atomic counter—a numeric attribute that is incremented,
>   unconditionally, without interfering with other write requests. (All
>   write requests are applied in the order in which they were received.)
>   With an atomic counter, the updates are not idempotent. In other
>   words, the numeric value increments each time you call UpdateItem.
>
> You might use an atomic counter to track the number of visitors to a
>   website. In this case, your application would increment a numeric
>   value, regardless of its current value. If an UpdateItem operation
>   fails, the application could simply retry the operation. This would
>   risk updating the counter twice, but you could probably tolerate a
>   slight overcounting or undercounting of website visitors.

Comment: This might cause hot key problem as one partition can have at most 3000 IOPS. 1 RCU=1 IOPS . 1 WCU =3 IOPS. Also it will be slow to use AtomicCounter as ID generator because increments are executed in serial.

Comment: Just to sum up (for myself and to help others): @vladaman s answer is actually showing this AtomicCounter technique.   And just as  @ guangtongShen has mentioned this technique is NOT scalable!  (I only use it on low-intensity operations. Eg. when "creating an item" happens very very rarely.   And usually this approach should be avoided in favor of UUIDs (as also mentioned in vladaman s request)

Comment: The link above mentions: An atomic counter would not be appropriate where overcounting or undercounting can't be tolerated (for example, in a banking application)

Answer (score 4):

Came across a similar issue, where I required auto-incrementing primary key in my table. We could use some randomization techniques to generate a random key and store it using that. But it won't be in a incremental fashion.

If you require something in incremental fashion, you can use [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as your primary key. Not assuring, that you can get a accurate incrementation(one-by-one), but yes every record you put, it would be in incremental fashion, with respect to the difference in how much time each record in inserted in.

Not a complete solution, if you don't want to read the entire table and get it's last `id` and then increment it.

Following is the code for inserting a record in DynamoDB using NodeJS:

```
.
.
        const params = {
            TableName: RANDOM_TABLE,
            Item: {
                ip: this.ip,
                id: new Date().getTime()
            }
        }
    
        dynamoDb.put(params, (error, result) => {
            console.log(error, result);
        });
.
.
```

Answer (score 4):

Update for 2022 :

I was looking for the same issue and came across following research.

DynamoDB still doesn't support auto-increment of primary keys.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/

Also the package [node-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uuid) is now deprecated. They recommend we use  [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package instead that creates  RFC4122 compliant UUID's.

```
npm install uuid

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NoSQL Dynamo DB then using Dynamoose, you can easily set default unique id, here is the simple user create example

// User.modal.js

```
const dynamoose = require("dynamoose");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const userSchema = new dynamoose.Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      hashKey: true,
    },
    displayName: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

const User = dynamoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

// User.controller.js

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({ id: uuidv4(), ...req.body }); // set unique id
  const [err, response] = await to(user.save());
  if (err) {
    return badRes(res, err);
  }
  return goodRes(res, reponse);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java developers, there is the [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html), which is a simple ORM. This supports the [DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey) annotation. It doesn't increment a numeric value like a typical "Long id", but rather generates a UUID like other answers here suggest. If you're mapping classes as you would with Hibernate, GORM, etc., this is more natural with less code.

I see no caveats in the docs about scaling issues. And it eliminates the issues with under or over-counting as you have with the auto-incremented numeric values (which the docs do call out).

Answer (score 0):

**A note on performance of uuid.v4()**

If you are making use of `uuid.v4()` from [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and care about performance than you can make use of built-in `crypto.randomUUID()` which is faster than uuid.v4(). Since under the hood, `uuid.v4()` makes use of `crypto.randomUUID()`.

Below post details the time comparison on both of the methods.

[crypto.randomUUID is three times faster uuid.v4](https://dev.to/galkin/crypto-randomuuid-vs-uuid-v4-47i5)