# DynamoDB partition key design with On-Demand

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How much do I need to care about partition key design with DynamoDB On-Demand and Adaptive Capacity?  What would happen if I tried to write to single partition key 40,000 times in one second?  Does the per-partition write request unit cap of 1,000 still exist such that it would throttle those 40,000 requests, or is there some magic that boosts that single partition temporarily up to the table limit?

It's not an arbitrary question, as I'd like to use incrementing integers for all our entities in DynamoDB via the method suggested within [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072341/how-to-use-auto-increment-for-primary-key-id-in-dynamodb) SO post, but that would require maintaining the latest id for an entity on a single partition key.  Every new item created would get their ID by writing to that partition key and inspecting the new value returned in the response.  If I were writing something like a chat app and using this method to get the new ID for each message, would my app only be able to create 1,000 new messages a second?

Comment: In the same thread you have this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899308/1692147
Would reconsider using that pattern with dynamo

Comment: Yes, #3 from that answer is the bit I was referring too.  If the 1k write limit still exits then I would indeed need to use either options #1 or #2 - thanks for the link!  One of the reason I was hoping to use simple incrementing integers is that the our model employs a lot of repeated Ids, so any space we can save on Id size directly impacts the amount of pagination we have to do on queries.