# Is it possible to create auto-inceremented partition key on cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-dynamodb-index

I need to create a cloudformation template for my dynamodb, but I need one of the indexes to be incremented automatically. CloudFormation template looks like this:

```
TestTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: test-event-records
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: “UniqueId”
          AttributeType: “N”
        - AttributeName: “IsRestored”
          AttributeType: “B”
        - AttributeName: “EventName”
          AttributeType: “S”
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: “UniqueId”
          KeyType: “HASH”
        - AttributeName: “IsRestored”
          KeyType: “HASH”
        - AttributeName: “EventName”
          KeyType: “HASH”
      Tags:
        - Key: “AppGroup”
          Value: !Ref “AppGroup”
        - Key: “AppRole”
          Value: “database”
        - Key: “Environment”
          Value: !Ref “Environment”
        - Key: “Name”
          Value: “test-event-records”
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
```

Here UniqueId (is of the type number and cannot be a UUID) has to be an auto-incremented value. I need to add new items to this new table in my .net core app.

Comment: I already seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072341/how-to-use-auto-increment-for-primary-key-id-in-dynamodb#:~:text=DynamoDB%20does%20not%20support%20auto,be%20up%20to%202048%20bytes. However it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Unrelated but please be careful with using any sort of editor which makes those "curly quotes". Those are not real quote characters and I expect if you copy/pasted that into a yaml file and tried to deploy it, it would fail.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I copied it from Brackets. I need to change its settings.

Comment: @Marcin I think I found my answer. It is not possible to do it from cloudformation. But it is possible to auto increment it in the code (in my case it is .netcore). I found this article very helpful https://andrewchaa.me.uk/technical/auto-increment-counter-in-dynamodb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible. CloudFormation nor DynamoDB provide such functionality. You must implement that in your application.