# How to generate unique ID with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
function generate(count) {
    var founded = false,
        _sym = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',
        str = '';
    while(!founded) {
        for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            str += _sym[parseInt(Math.random() * (_sym.length))];
        }
        base.getID(string, function(err, res) {
            if(!res.length) {
                founded = true; // How to do it?
            }
        });
    }
    return str;
}
```

How to set a variable value with database query callback? How I can do it?

Comment: @JamesAllardice, I need to understand how this can be done with a database query. Sorry, thanks.

Comment: This question is incorrectly flagged as a duplicate. The linked question answers how to do it in generic javascript; the highest rated answer in this question is specific to node.js.

Comment: I would love to paste this as an answer: `var hexstring = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");` followed by `var guidstring = hexstring.substring(0,8) + "-" + hexstring.substring(8,12) + "-" + hexstring.substring(12,16) + "-" + hexstring.substring(16,20) + "-" + hexstring.substring(20);`

Comment: This is a good answer with `new mongo.ObjectID();` and manually https://stackoverflow.com/a/56106999/4701635

Comment: @selbie Your result only *looks* like a UUID and is not always a valid UUID. This might break assumptions of any downstream code. If you just need a random identifier, then use your `hextring`, which is perfect. If you need a UUID, create one with a library in the proper format/version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's been some time since I used node.js, but I think I might be able to help.

Firstly, in node, you only have a single thread and are supposed to use callbacks. What will happen with your code, is that `base.getID` query will get queued up by for execution, but the `while` loop will continusouly run as a busy loop pointlessly.

You should be able to solve your issue with a callback as follows:

```
function generate(count, k) {
    var _sym = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',
    var str = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        str += _sym[parseInt(Math.random() * (_sym.length))];
    }
    base.getID(str, function(err, res) {
        if(!res.length) {
          k(str)                   // use the continuation
        } else generate(count, k)  // otherwise, recurse on generate
    });
}
```

And use it as such

```
generate(10, function(uniqueId){
  // have a uniqueId
})
```

I haven't coded any node/js in around 2 years and haven't tested this, but the basic idea should hold – don't use a busy loop, and use callbacks. You might want to have a look at the node async package.

Comment: Math.random is a poor choice when a truly random ID is needed, especially if it needs to be unpredictable / cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 551):

Install NPM [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package (sources: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid):

```bash
npm install uuid
```

and use it in your code, e.g. with ES6 imports:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4, v6 as uuidv6 } from 'uuid';

uuidv4();
uuidv6();
```

Or with CommonJS requires:

```
const { 
  v1: uuidv1,
  v4: uuidv4,
} = require('uuid');

uuidv1(); // -> '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a' 
uuidv4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

For

Comment: thanks, but I need to do it with a database query. :)

Comment: @owl I don't understand what you mean. In SQL ?

Comment: What difference does it make if it's in a db query? You have a unique id, now use it in whichever interface you use to communicate with your databse.

Comment: Any idea what's the difference between the packages uuid and node-uuid ?

Comment: Taking a look at the source, this not not ensure **uniqueness**. This is merely a random UUID generator

Comment: @Downgoad No it does not assure 100% uniqueness, but is very close.
So close that you can almost use it as such if you are creating documents with it. Apply a unique constrain to your database on the id field and voilá.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid

Comment: @ishandutta2007 node-uuid is deprecated: "DEPRECATED: Use the uuid package instead."

Comment: The accepted answer should show how to implement UUID generation in node.js - not how to use someone else's implementation.

Comment: i tried using with with socket-io. and seems to break require socket (2.0.3)

Comment: gives me following error when tried following in node REPL - value must be an array of bytes
    at generateUUID (/node_modules/uuid/lib/v35.js:29:38)

Comment: i dont like that the edited version of this answer is copied from another answer. like literally

Comment: @Sgnl I didn't edit it, but at least the most visible answer is up to date

Comment: Every time that I want to create a new GUID i have to create a new const ? `const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');`

Comment: @user3796130 no need just call the function again

Comment: @Downgoat, `crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex")` vs. `uuidv4()`, what's a preferable option? The first one is built-in into Node.js.

Comment: nodejs `v15.6.0` now supports `crypto.randomUUID();`

Comment: @FilipSeman According to docs it is already "Added in: v14.17.0" (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomuuid_options) which is tue and saved my day.

Answer (score 461):

The fastest possible way to create random 32-char string in Node is by using native `crypto` module:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const id = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");

console.log(id); // => f9b327e70bbcf42494ccb28b2d98e00e
```

Comment: I like this solution because no external dependency is needed. Also I found base64 version is useuful too. `crypto.randomBytes(3*4).toString('base64') //=> '9uzHqCOWI9Kq2Jdw'`

Comment: Is it random or unique? Please elaborate random function.

Comment: 'Generates cryptographically strong pseudo-random data.' [API](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)

Comment: `crypto` is now built into node itself.. You get this warning if you npm install it: `crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in`

Comment: Make sure you don't use crypto.randomBytes() with large numbers. Also, it can be slow right after the OS boots up. Read the docs for more info: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback

Comment: This now causes deprecation warnings.

Comment: @Pono does this gives a unique value or random value?

Comment: This could give a url unfriendly string since characters like `/` are included

Comment: A little one liner to help get it in UUID format
`[8,4,4,4,12].map(n => crypto.randomBytes(n/2).toString("hex")).join("-")`

Comment: do we have to worry about collisions?

Comment: @JonathanScialpi make a longer string, virtually no collisions

Comment: Just want to clarify that Greg's solution doesn't technically create an actual UUID, since they have certain bytes that are non-random. It should still work for all intents and purposes, however.

Answer (score 233):

Since Node 14.17.0 you can now use the built-in crypto module to generate UUIDs (UUIDv4 Flavored):

```
const { randomUUID } = require('crypto'); // Added in: node v14.17.0

console.log(randomUUID());

// '89rct5ac2-8493-49b0-95d8-de843d90e6ca'
```

For more you can explore
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomuuid_options

Note: `crypto.randomUUID` is three times faster than uuid. And no need to add extra dependency.

Comment: The comment is incorrect.  crypto.randomUUID() works in v14 of node https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomuuid_options

Comment: You may have to install `@types/node` for this to work.

Comment: @types/node is required only if you are using TypeScript.

Comment: @DheerajkumarRao even without TypeScript, `@types/node` package will help IDE auto-completion. I strongly recommend using it.

Answer (score 56):

Simple, time based, without dependencies:

```js
(new Date()).getTime().toString(36)
```

or

```js
Date.now().toString(36)
```

Output: `jzlatihl`

---

plus random number (Thanks to @Yaroslav Gaponov's answer)

```js
(new Date()).getTime().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
```

Output `jzlavejjperpituute`

Comment: Beware: I highly discourage this solution for any important app:  such client's "time-dependent" unique id is an absolutely **NO-GO** .  though adding random number (as mention in the end of th epost) helps it.

Answer (score 47):

edit: shortid has been deprecated. The maintainers recommend to use [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) instead.

---

Another approach is using the [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) package from npm.

It is very easy to use:

```
var shortid = require('shortid');
console.log(shortid.generate()); // e.g. S1cudXAF
```

and has some compelling features:

> ShortId creates amazingly short non-sequential url-friendly unique
> ids. Perfect for url shorteners, MongoDB and Redis ids, and any other
> id users might see.
>
> - By default 7-14 url-friendly characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _-
> - Non-sequential so they are not predictable.
> - Can generate any number of ids without duplicates, even millions per day.
> - Apps can be restarted any number of times without any chance of repeating an id.

Comment: "Apps can be restarted any number of times without any chance of repeating an id.?"

Can you show me how shortid works?

Comment: @NavyFlame Here you go: https://github.com/dylang/shortid or more specifically https://github.com/dylang/shortid/issues/95

Comment: "shortid is deprecated, because the architecture is unsafe. we instead recommend Nano ID, which has the advantage of also being significantly faster than shortid" https://github.com/ai/nanoid

Answer (score 23):

`node-uuid` is deprecated so please use `uuid`

```
npm install uuid --save
// Generate a v1 UUID (time-based) 
const uuidV1 = require('uuid/v1');
uuidV1(); // -> '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a' 

// Generate a v4 UUID (random) 
const uuidV4 = require('uuid/v4');
uuidV4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

[Npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Answer (score 18):

More easy and without addition modules

```
Math.random().toString(26).slice(2)
```

Comment: I think it depends on length. so you can extend this code like this  

inline `function getId(mask) {
    return mask.replace(/[x]/gi, () => {
        return Math.random().toString(26)[5];
    })
}


console.log(getId('xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'));`

Comment: Math.random is a poor choice when a truly random ID is needed, especially if it needs to be unpredictable / cryptographically secure.

Comment: This will not generate a truly universally unique id.

Comment: @JechoJekov "truly random" ? I doubt it

Comment: Yes [YaroslavGaponov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3778960/yaroslav-gaponov) could be correct as the chances of fractions being the same in a real space [0, 1] is 0. Wrote code to generate 1,000,000 Math.random() and could not find any duplicates. ```random_numbers = []
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    random_numbers.push(Math.random())
}
if (i === 1000000) {
    console.log("Before checking duplicate")
    console.log(random_numbers.length)
    console.log("After checking duplicate")
    random_set = new Set(random_numbers)
    console.log([...random_set].length) }```

Comment: @YiXiangChong, if there's no chance of duplicates with "Math.random()", there's a problem. It's no longer randomness.

Answer (score 13):

If you use node v15.6.0+ us can use `crypto.randomUUID([options])`. Full documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomuuid_options).

Comment: This is the correct answer for the current version of Node.

Comment: Added in: v15.6.0, v14.17.0

Answer (score 12):

to install uuid

```
npm install --save uuid
```

uuid is updated and the old import

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
```

is not working and we should now use this import

```
const {v4: uuid} = require('uuid');
```

and for using it use as a function like this

```
const  createdPlace = {
    id: uuid(),
    title,
    description,
    location: coordinates,
    address,
    creator
  };
```

Answer (score 9):

My 5 cents:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const generateUuid = () => {
  return [4, 2, 2, 2, 6] // or 8-4-4-4-12 in hex
    .map(group => crypto.randomBytes(group).toString('hex'))
    .join('-');
};
```

[Pono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40191779/2750743)'s string lacked hyphens sadly, so it did not conform to the [uuid standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format), which is what I believe most people came here for.

```js
> generateUuid();
'143c8862-c212-ccf1-e74e-7c9afa78d871'
> generateUuid();
'4d02d4d6-4c0d-ea6b-849a-208b60bfb62e'
```

Comment: crypto is deprecated as far as I see. https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto

Recommended https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

So to note : You don't need to run `npm install crypto` - just reference it as above.

Comment: Yeah, `crypto` is a built-in module. The deprecated module in npm is just some random package that incidentally has same name.

Answer (score 5):

If some one needs cryptographic-strong UUID, there is solution for that as well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-safe-id

```
npm install generate-safe-id
```

> Why not UUIDs?
>
> Random UUIDs (UUIDv4) **do not have enough entropy** to be universally
>   unique (ironic, eh?). Random UUIDs have only **122 bits** of entropy,
>   which suggests that a duplicate will occur after only **2^61** IDs.
>   Additionally, some UUIDv4 implementations do not use a
>   cryptographically strong random number generator.
>
> This library generates **240-bit** IDs using the Node.js crypto RNG,
>   suggesting the first duplicate will occur after generating **2^120** IDs.
>   Based on the current energy production of the human race, this
>   threshold will be impossible to cross for the foreseeable future.

```
var generateSafeId = require('generate-safe-id');

var id = generateSafeId();
// id == "zVPkWyvgRW-7pSk0iRzEhdnPcnWfMRi-ZcaPxrHA"
```

Comment: This is answer may no longer work for users due to `generate-safe-id` being abandoned AND security vulnerabilities not being fixed (as of August 2018)

Answer (score 3):

i want to use this

```js
class GUID {
    Generate() {
    const hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    const model = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
      var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length);
      str += model[i] == "x" ?  hex[rnd] : model[i] ;
    }
    return str.toLowerCase();
  }
}
 
console.log(new GUID().Generate());
console.log(new GUID().Generate());
console.log(new GUID().Generate());
console.log(new GUID().Generate());
console.log(new GUID().Generate());
```

Comment: deployed to production! thanks :)

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu You're about to get hacked big time.

Comment: no one did not use this for bank account . for more secure u can add more secure random generator

Answer (score 2):

[nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) achieves exactly the same thing that you want.

Example usage:

```js
const { nanoid } = require("nanoid")

console.log(nanoid())
//=> "n340M4XJjATNzrEl5Qvsh"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use urid package `npm install urid`

```
import urid from 'urid';

urid(); // qRpky22nKJ4vkbFZ
```

Read full docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/urid

```
// Set the size
urid(8); //ZDJLC0Zq

// Use the character set
urid('num'); // 4629118294212196
urid('alpha'); // ebukmhyiagonmmbm
urid('alphanum'); // nh9glmi1ra83979b

// Use size with character set
urid(12, 'alpha'); // wwfkvpkevhbg

// use custom character set
urid(6, '0123456789ABCDEF'); // EC58F3
urid('0123456789ABCDEF'); // 6C11044E128FB44B

// some more samples
urid()               // t8BUFCUipSEU4Ink
urid(24)             // lHlr1pIzAUAOyn1soU8atLzJ
urid(8, 'num')       // 12509986
urid(8, 'alpha')     // ysapjylo
urid(8, 'alphanum')  // jxecf9ad

// example of all character sets
urid('num')          // 5722278852141945
urid('alpha')        // fzhjrnrkyxralgpl
urid('alphanum')     // l5o4kfnrhr2cj39w
urid('Alpha')        // iLFVgxzzUFqxzZmr
urid('ALPHA')        // ALGFUIJMZJILJCCI
urid('ALPHANUM')     // 8KZYKY6RJWZ89OWH
urid('hex')          // 330f726055e92c51
urid('HEX')          // B3679A52C69723B1

// custom character set
urid('ABCD-')        // ACA-B-DBADCD-DCA
```

Comment: you also can use *urid.default(16)* if you facce any issues

Answer (score 2):

Here is one benchmark for current solutions refer to [nanoid benchmark](https://github.com/ai/nanoid#benchmark)

```js
import { v4 as uuid4 } from 'uuid'
import benchmark from 'benchmark'
import shortid from 'shortid'

let suite = new benchmark.Suite()

suite
  .add('crypto.randomUUID', () => {
    crypto.randomUUID()
  })
  .add('nanoid', () => {
    nanoid()
  })
  .add('uuid v4', () => {
    uuid4()
  })
  .add("math.random", () => {
    (new Date()).getTime().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
  })
  .add('crypto.randomBytes', () => {
    crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex')
  })
  .add('shortid', () => {
    shortid()
  })
  .on('cycle', event => {
    let name = event.target.name
    let hz = formatNumber(event.target.hz.toFixed(0)).padStart(10)

    process.stdout.write(`${name}${pico.bold(hz)}${pico.dim(' ops/sec')}\n`)
  })
  .run()
```

The result is

```
node ./test/benchmark.js
crypto.randomUUID         13,281,440 ops/sec
nanoid                     3,278,757 ops/sec
uuid v4                    1,117,140 ops/sec
math.random                1,206,105 ops/sec
crypto.randomBytes           280,199 ops/sec
shortid                       30,728 ops/sec
```

Test env:

- 2.6 GHz 6Cores Intel Core i7 MacOS
- Node v16.17.0

Answer (score 2):

```js
const uniqueId = self.crypto.randomUUID();
console.log(uniqueId)
```

- The randomUUID() method of the Crypto interface is used to generate a v4 UUID using a cryptographically secure random number generator.
- Return A string containing a randomly generated, 36 character long v4 UUID.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following and it is working fine plus without any third-party dependencies.

```
const {
  randomBytes
} = require('crypto');

const uid = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2) + randomBytes(8).toString('hex') + new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Note that the UUID is not just random bits, and follow a specific structure. An UUID generated from random number (or encoding arbitrary information) is defined in RFC4122 as "version 4", and has two specific group of bits, length 2 and 4 respectively, set to specific values. The remaining 122 bits can be anything. But they are non-contiguous. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.4

Answer (score 1):

The solutions here are old and now deprecated: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#deep-requires-now-deprecated

Use this:

> npm install uuid

```
//add these lines to your code
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
var your_uuid = uuidv4();
console.log(your_uuid);
```

Answer (score 1):

used https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid in npm

```
npm i uniqid
```

It will always create unique id's based on the current time, process and machine name.

- With the current time the ID's are always unique in a single process.
- With the Process ID the ID's are unique even if called at the same
  time from multiple processes.
- With the MAC Address the ID's are unique even if called at the same
  time from multiple machines and processes.

**Features:-**

- Very fast
- Generates unique id's on multiple processes and machines even if
  called at the same time.
- Shorter 8 and 12 byte versions with less uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Extending from [YaroslavGaponov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3778960/yaroslav-gaponov)'s answer, the simplest implementation is just using `Math.random()`.

```
Math.random()
```

Mathematically, the chances of fractions being the same in a real space [0, 1] is theoretically 0. Probability-wise it is approximately close to 0 for a default length of 16 decimals in node.js. And this implementation should also reduce arithmetic overflows as no operations are performed. Also, it is more memory efficient compared to a string as Decimals occupy less memory than strings.

I call this the **"Fractional-Unique-ID"**.

Wrote code to generate 1,000,000 `Math.random()` numbers and could not find any duplicates (at least for default decimal points of 16). See code below (please provide feedback if any):

```
random_numbers = [] 
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { 
   random_numbers.push(Math.random()); 
   //random_numbers.push(Math.random().toFixed(13)) //depends decimals default 16 
} 

if (i === 1000000) { 
   console.log("Before checking duplicate"); 
   console.log(random_numbers.length); 
   console.log("After checking duplicate"); 
   random_set = new Set(random_numbers); // Set removes duplicates
   console.log([...random_set].length); // length is still the same after removing
}
```

Comment: Also, it depends on the number of decimals. I found that above 13 decimals ```random_numbers.push(Math.random().toFixed(13))``` still give the same length

Answer (score 0):

Generates cryptographically strong pseudorandom data. The size argument is a number indicating the number of bytes to generate.

```
// Asynchronous
const {
  randomBytes,
} = require('crypto');

randomBytes(256, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`${buf.length} bytes of random data: unique random ID ${buf.toString('hex')}`);
});
```

[Know more](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/crypto.html#cryptorandombytessize-callback)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way to get unique id is the `time`, and I use `hash` for that example

```js
const hash = require('object-hash');
const user = { ..., iat: Date.now() }
const user_id = hash(user)

console.log(user_id) // ex. 49686bab1a2276e0b1bd61ccc86f8156
```

and that is how I actually get unique identifier in any aspect. because in real world time never repeats.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let count = 0;
let previous = 0;
const generateUniqueId = () => {
  const time = new Date().getTime()
  count = time > previous ? 0 : (++count)
  const uid = time + count
  previous = uid
  return uid
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`var uid = new ShortUniqueId(); var id = uid();`

//add cdn link of ShortUniqueId in index.html body just above your script.js

Comment: I would recommend adding all steps to the suggested answer instead of writing "add cdn link of ShortUniqueId"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).