# how to generate unique key hash in combination two model attribute in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to generate `hash` in a combination of two model attribute.

I have schema like this

```
const BlogPost = new Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  empid: String,
  date: Date
});
```

I want to create a unique `id` which is `hash` of the combination  `empid and date`.if same `hash` is generated it `gives` me error.
can we generate `unique` in a combination of `empid and date` ?

Same hash will be generated if we pass `empid and date`? then it gives me error

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-tree-hd0fo

```
try {
    var blog = new BlogPostModel({
      empid: "test123",
      date: "19-Jul-2019"
    });
    console.log("before save");
    let saveBlog = await blog.save(); //when fail its goes to catch
    console.log(saveBlog); //when success it print.
    console.log("saveBlog save");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) library for this before. Node also has a built in [md5 hash library](https://gist.github.com/kitek/1579117)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here sorry, but I was able to find this stack overflow answer for uuid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23327039/12060701