# How can I generate unique shareable links like zoom and google hangouts do?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, agora.io

I am creating a group video chat application and I am trying to generate unique shareable links for each chat room someone starts up. How can I create that? I want when a user shares these links, others can join the channel. Kind of like how zoom and google hangouts work. I tried finding an answer for this but have failed

I'm building my application using HTML, CSS, Javascript, Node, Express, and Agora.io

Comment: Long answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707677/13378247 Short answer: `Math.random()`

Answer (score 0):

I use next way (result hash something like "885b1aca1cfde894a9c2cd7c7a755152"):

```
const hash = Array(32)
      .fill(null)
      .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 16).toString(16))
      .join('');

const link = `${www.your-host.name}/${some-path}/?v=${hash}` //its just example
```