# Is there a chance the uid's genrated from uuid package can be same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I want to generate `unique` uid for objects which will be stored in database.
I am using [UUID npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate unique id.
I want to know is there a chance that any of the id's generated by this package can repeat themselves? like the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38944736/13126651 speaks about nano id package and how it doesnt generate duplicates, is there same conviction for uuid package too?

ofcourse there can be solution to check database before storing but since this will I/o operation i want to avoid this and since this will be in REST API so i cant even maintain state.

Note :- i am specualting that my API will hit around 1000 times in a day so is there chance of repeating uid's?

Update :- [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid) this question talks about how UUID are unique but if someone can explain does UUID npm package does something extra to ensure it never repeats?

Comment: Duplicate of [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid)

Comment: If you are only ever generating UUIDs from one server process, then you can guarantee it is unique by appending an increasing counter to it.  Each time you generate one, you increase the value of the counter and append the new value to the end of the UUID such as `lkasjfAalsjf-4` where the `-4` is from your counter.  The laws of probability would say you probably don't need to do that, but if you still aren't sure, you can force it unique with the counter.  And, you have to persistently store the counter so if your server restarts, the counter value is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot:

> No, a UUID can't be guaranteed to be unique. A UUID is just a 128-bit random number. When my computer generates a UUID, there's no practical way it can prevent your computer or any other device in the universe from generating that same UUID at some time in the future.

Comment: here computer is not generating that, its the package, i want to know specifically in regards to that npm package

Comment: there is a 1 in 7 billion chance it can be the same, which means trillions of uuids in a year to get only about 1-3 duplicates

Comment: is there a link or documentation associated with your above statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid

Comment: mark this as the answer if this is the thing you wanted