# How to generate automatically ClientID for Adobe PDF Embed API

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, jira, adobe-embed-api

I have developed a jira-plugin that can be installed in many instances of jira having different domains.
Is there any API or another way to generate the client ID's automatically that I can use it in my plugin-code-source by giving her only the domain as input and it returns the client ID as output?

Comment: You can generate your own IDs using pure JavaScript as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23328916/14267427).

Comment: Which Id are you looking to gain? And are you on Cloud, Server, or Datacenter. Based on the instance type, what plugin development platform are you using?

Comment: @Tyler2P - Your comment is incorrect. The clientID for Adobe PDF Embed API requires credentials generated by Adobe. It is not a UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the clientID can only be generated via the adobe.io console.