# Why I'm getting collisions on UUID v4 generated with node 16 on Cloud Run?

Tags: node.js, uuid, google-cloud-run

I'm getting a lot of collisions, at least 5 on the last 100.000 generated UUID. Right now wea are checking that generated UUID with a redis instance, so if a collision happen, we can regenerate it.

The service has at least 2 instances always running.

the UUID is generated with

```
crypto.randomUUID()
```

Comment: Are you **seeding** the random number generator first? Otherwise, you will have predictable pseudo random numbers which UUID uses.

Comment: @JohnHanley but I'm using the "Crypto" library. It's supose to be cryptographically secure

Comment: I do not use your library, but each one I have used does require seeding the random number generator. The first clue is that you are generating duplicate UUIDs.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Comment: Since you are having UUID collisions that should **never** happen, investigate your code to find out why that is occurring.

Comment: @JohnHanley it's the native method of node

Comment: That is why I am suggesting your code has the problem. Otherwise, the library has the problem and I doubt that at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I can only asume they are looking at [this method](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandomuuidoptions) and it does not allow a seed parameter.

I am not sure why this would happen but might have been coincidence that 5 ids were repeated. I suggest looking at [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327010/how-to-generate-unique-id-with-node-js) people have tried, such as including `date.now()` in order to truly never get a repeat.

Comment: Well, Looking the the docs that you posted, I see that it has by default a "cache of random data". So I will test again with it disabled 

crypto.randomUUID({ disableEntropyCache: true })

Answer (score 0):

In UUID's npm page shows support only up to node 14, is that the problem? [https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L06lL.png)

Comment: I'm not using a package, is the oficial crypto module from node, currently suppoerted ( https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html )