# Creating "users.id_users" on DynamoDB and PHP

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm studing DynamoDB but I don't understand how can I create a unique user's id foreach user. In SQL is simple, there is an int (AI) field.
It'll be a int value because each user's profile url is like (very common form):

```
my-application-url/users/[:id_users]
ex. my-application-url/users/1/
```

My old save_users function is:

```
public function save_users($users){ 
 if($users->id == 0){
    $this->tableGateway()->save($users);
 }else{
    $this->tableGateway()->update($users, 'id_users' => (int) $users->id);
 }
}
```

I use zend framework 2.

I could get the last registered user's id and increment it, but if I have 2 or more simultaneus registrations, I could get 2 or more identical user's id.

the users dynamodb table it also simple:

```
{
  "id_users" Number: 1,
  "firstname" String: "Alessandro",
  "lastname" String: "Corradini",
  "email" String: "my-email",
  "password" String: "my-encrypted-password"
}
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I need a UUID field into users table. The table 'll be like:

```
{
  "UUID" String : <UUID-placeholder>,
  "id_users" Number: 1,
  "firstname" String: "Alessandro",
  "lastname" String: "Corradini",
  "email" String: "my-email",
  "password" String: "my-encrypted-password"
}
```

For `id_users` identifier, also unique, I'll generate a fixed lenght `id_users` with this function below. Before saving user into `register.php`, I'll check if is present into table (and email also!!), if is not, save user, else generate another unique id.

```
 function randomId($length){
    $result = mt_rand(1, 9);

    for($i = 0; $i < ($length - 1); $i++) {
        $result .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }

    return $result;
 }
```

For 16 character length, I have 10^16 combinations. I think that is enaugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the approach in dynamodb is to create an UUID in your client side, for example by timestamp (instead of auto-increment feature)

you can also use an external service that provide you the id (by using locks on global verb)

you can get more information here:

Are autoincremented primary keys okay
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=561190

[How to make a UUID in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721308/how-to-make-a-uuid-in-dynamodb)

https://www.quora.com/How-to-auto-increment-in-DynamoDB

Comment: ok, I'll ad a UUID item. For "id_users" field I create a function than return a  long integer for a fixed lenght (ex. 16).

`function randomId($length){
    $result = mt_rand(1, 9);

    for($i = 0; $i < ($length - 1); $i++) {
        $result .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }

    return $result;
 }`

Comment: I just add the solution in the first post because I can't format the comment :( . It's a correct solution?

Comment: Why not creating user id by timestamp? You can keep like this your user id incremented , so the higher user id is the latest created. You can also use composite (random +timestamp)