# unique id for each item in dynamodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm using **dynamodb** and I'm trying to **set** a different **unique** **value** ( ***id*** ) for **each item** I create **in** a **table**.

While looking for a solution I find the "**atomic counter**" solution and in the docs of aws there is an example [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.04) ( *Increment an Atomic Counter* ), but what id does is **just** to **update** **items** and **not** **adding** the id **when** the item is **created**.

How can I do that?

Comment: To directly address what you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721308/how-to-make-a-uuid-in-dynamodb From a data architecture side I would consider trying to use meaningful primary keys when using DynamoDB, but also generating UUIDs for each entry can work (they won't be sequential- which is intentional since it keeps DynamoDB scalable)

Comment: Yeah actually the easiest solution was using an uuid, so I don't have to do tricky stuff

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work!